# Can I bring computer parts to Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia

I'm a foreigner who moved to Australia a year ago. I've been looking to build my first gaming PC, BUT as I've look in some computer stores in Australia, the parts are a little bit expensive for me. When I checked the parts in the country where I came from (Thailand) it is way cheaper than here.

If I fly from Australia to Thailand and buy all the parts, then bring them back to Australia, am I allowed to bring them in? Am I going to get charged by customs for bringing it in?

Answer (score 14):

If you are 18 or older, Australia allows you to bring AUD900 of "general goods", which includes electronics, [without paying duty](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/can-you-bring-it-in/categories/duty-free).

If you exceed AUD900 in goods, you are liable to pay duty and tax on all of the goods you're bringing in, not just the excess, so make sure not to exceed it (so for example, if you buy your PC parts for AUD850, don't also buy some jewellery for AUD100, since you'll then be taxed on all AUD950 of your goods).

Under the duty free limit, you do not need to declare your goods, but you should make sure to hold on to your receipts, in case you are inspected at customs.

Comment: Leave a bit of wiggle room too. Customs will use the currency exchange rate on the day you enter Australia, not the day you purchased the goods.

Comment: are laptops excluded ? most good laptops are anyways over 900 .. what happens in that case?

Comment: @NigelFds I've not checked the Aus rules, but I would not expect so. If you bring in a $2000 laptop, legally you'd be required to pay the appropriate duties and taxes.

Comment: My experience (*not in Australia but in other countries*) is if you speak to customs and bring a laptop that you've had for a while, they'll probably not make you pay tax. But then, the Australian government is known for being authoritarian.

Comment: @NigelFds This is specifically for goods which you are *importing*. If you own a laptop and take it out of the country and then return with it, or you bring your laptop in for a temporary visit, it does not count as importing. Also, there are different rules if you are moving to Australia and bringing in your personal effects. If you are resident in Australia and you return with a brand new laptop, yes, you'd need to pay duty on it (unless it's worth less than AUD900).

Comment: @user253751 You don't need to declare your laptop when you enter the country routinely, just as you don't need to declare your wedding ring, smart phone, or any valuable clothes or handbags you're carrying as part of your personal effects. It's only when you are *importing* goods that declaration could be required. Customs officers know what to look for (pristine electronics in their original packaging for example).

Comment: @MJeffryes Why does it not count as importing?

Comment: @user253751 An import which could be subject to duty happens when goods are brought permanently into the country. When goods are returning with a passenger who temporarily took them out the country or are being brought into the country temporarily by a visitor, they are not subject to duty. Observe that customs is not full of people declaring the watches they are wearing, nor their smart phones, nor their jewelry to customs officers.

Comment: @MJeffryes How does customs know that you only brought it out temporarily? I have always been told: if in doubt, declare it - chances are the customs agent will wave you through, which is better than potentially getting a large fine for not declaring something.

Comment: @user253751 They can use context like, is it being transported in its original packaging, is there wear and tear, are you carrying more than 1 laptop. If you want to declare your laptop every time you enter a country, it's up to you. It would be very unusual behavior, and I would not recommend it. But this discussion isn't going anywhere, so let's leave it at that.